# Django db reset without loading fixtures

Tags: python, database, django, fixtures

Is there an easy way to reset a django database (i.e. drop all data/tables, create new tables and create indexes) without loading fixture data afterwords? What I want to have is just an empty database because all data is loaded from another source (a kind of a post-processed backup).

I know that this could  be achieved by piping the output of the `manage sql...` commands to `manage dbshell`, but this relies on `manage dbshell`and is kind of hacky...

Are there any other ways to do this?

Edit:
`manage reset` will do it, but is there a command like `reset` that doesn't need the application names as parameters?

Comment: the answers from shylent and avisser are correct, but is there a command where I don't need to supply all the application names (like `syncdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the fixtures (in initial_data file) are automatically loaded after `manage.py syndcb` and not after reset. So, if you do a `manage.py reset yourapp` it should not load the fixtures. Hmm?

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't you be able do do this with manage.py's [reset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/django-admin/#reset-appname-appname) option?